# How do I fit an equation to this butterfly curve?

Tags: regression, machine-learning

[image: Butterfly curve]

I have data which I plotted to visualize. I cant seem to fit any sort of sensible curve to this plot and I wondered how do I approach this task?

Comment: What have you tried? There are tons of function approximators. Two hints are to use a function $f:\mathbb{R} \mapsto \mathbb{R}^2$ and reflect half of your data.

Comment: I've tried exponential,fourier, guassian, polynomial,ect

Comment: The plot does not show it but the data points on the sides are sparse

Comment: How many terms did you use in the partial Fourier expansion? And what degree of poylnomials? And did you put them into a $f:\mathbb{R} \mapsto \mathbb{R}^2$ vector function?

Comment: I'm using matlab and I went through 1-9 in polynomials and 1 to 8 terms in the fourier series. Where can I find these function approximators that take in a real number and put out two real numbers?

Comment: Ah, not using a map $f: \mathbb{R} \mapsto \mathbb{R}^2$ is probably the issue. Look at how any function that you would fit your data in Cartesian coordinates would fail the vertical line test. You can define the vector function $f(t) = [h(t), g(t)]^T$ where $h$ and $g$ are whatever function approximators you like. You will need to choose a parametrization of your curve with parameter $t$, which I would take to be a subset of $[0, 1]$ for simplicity.

Comment: What would i do in matlab to pull this off

Comment: Sorry, I don't know Matlab.

Comment: No worries, @Galen can you point me to softwares which might do this

Comment: Pretty much any programming language. I'm sure Matlab can do this. For polynomial approximation you can put all of the coefficients into a matrix and your polynomial features into a matrix and use linear fitting methods.

Comment: This does not look like a statistics question You might want to look at the [batman curve](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/54506/is-this-batman-equation-for-real).